# Visible light source in JavaFX 3D

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am currently studying JavaFX 3D capabilities, and I would like to model the solar system. I am quite successful in creating a light source of type `PointLight`, and set its coordinates bound to sun's coordinates. Now I would like to see the sun glows with its radiance as the light source. How would I do that?

```
@Component
public class RootPane extends StackPane {

    @Inject
    protected Scene scene;

    @Inject
    protected PerspectiveCamera camera;

    @Inject
    protected LightBase lightBase;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setPadding(new Insets(20));

        Sphere sunSphere = new Sphere(80);
        sunSphere.setEffect(new Glow(5));

        Sphere mercurySphere = new Sphere(40);
        mercurySphere.translateZProperty().bind(sunSphere.translateZProperty()
                .add(200));

        Sphere venusSphere = new Sphere(40);
        venusSphere.translateXProperty().bind(sunSphere.translateXProperty()
                .subtract(300));
        venusSphere.translateZProperty().bind(sunSphere.translateZProperty()
                .subtract(300));

        Sphere earthSphere = new Sphere(40);
        earthSphere.translateXProperty().bind(sunSphere.translateXProperty()
                .add(300));
        earthSphere.translateZProperty().bind(sunSphere.translateZProperty()
                .subtract(400));

        Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
        Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        Rotate rotateZ = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);

        Translate translate = new Translate(0, 0, -3000);

        camera.getTransforms().addAll(rotateX, rotateY, rotateZ, translate);

        scene.addEventHandler(
                KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                event -> {
                    if (Objects.equals(event.getCode(), KeyCode.D)) {
                        rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() - 
                                (event.isShiftDown() ? 5 : 0.1));
                    } else if (Objects.equals(event.getCode(), KeyCode.A)) {
                        rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() + 
                                (event.isShiftDown() ? 5 : 0.1));
                    }
                });
        scene.addEventHandler(
                KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                event -> {
                    if (Objects.equals(event.getCode(), KeyCode.W)) {
                        rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() - 
                                (event.isShiftDown() ? 5 : 0.1));
                    } else if (Objects.equals(event.getCode(), KeyCode.S)) {
                        rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() + 
                                (event.isShiftDown() ? 5 : 0.1));
                    }
                });

        lightBase.translateXProperty().bind(sunSphere.translateXProperty());
        lightBase.translateYProperty().bind(sunSphere.translateYProperty());
        lightBase.translateZProperty().bind(sunSphere.translateZProperty());

        getChildren().addAll(sunSphere, mercurySphere, venusSphere,
                earthSphere, camera, lightBase);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this your full code?  Can you include where you're initializing scene, camera, lightBase, etc.

Comment: You can't see point light source. It's a point, it has 0 area. You see the Sun because it has area of ~2.35×10^12 square miles, half of which is emitting your way. You need to simulate the appearance using same approach you have for planets, maybe add some effects like aura, glare, etc.

Comment: Oh, I see you have a sunSphere. Maybe you mean 'god rays' effect?

Comment: @IceGlow: I just want to see the sun brightened with its radiance.

Comment: @IceGlow To mimic the color of the sun, I added a `PhongMaterial` with `Color.YELLOW` as its diffuse color. When light is tuned off, it is visible. If light is turned on, the material could not be seen, as if the sun is turning into a black hole.

Answer (score 1):

Without an example of the effect you are looking to achieve it is hard to provide an answer but here are Two options:

Create a particle effect emitting from the sun with additive blending

Create a material with a specular map.

Comment: I added a `PhongMaterial` with `Color.YELLOW` as its diffuse color in the `sunSphere`, but is not visible when the light is turned on. (The `PointLight`'s coordinates are bound to `sunSphere`'s.

Answer (score 1):

From [PhongMaterial JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/PhongMaterial.html)

> The color is computed by the following equation:
>
> ```
> for each ambient light source i {
>     ambient += lightColor[i]
> }
> for each point light source i {
>     diffuse += (L[i] . N) * lightColor[i]
>     specular += ((R[i] . V) ^ (specularPower * intensity(specularMap))) * lightColor[i]
> }
> color = (ambient + diffuse) * diffuseColor * diffuseMap
>          + specular * specularColor * specularMap
>          + selfIlluminationMap
> ```
>
> where:
>
> lightColor[i] is the color of light source i,
>
> L[i] is the vector from the surface to light source i,
>
> N is the normal vector (taking into the account the bumpMap if present),
>
> R[i] is the normalized reflection vector for L[i] about the surface normal,
>
> and V is the normalized view vector.

If your PointLight coordinates match your Sun's Sphere coordinates, then L[i] . N < 0 and you have no diffuse contribution. So, in the absence of ambient light it'll look black.

Try to add that selfIlluminationMap they have mentioned using sun texture. It should help.

A brief search on google gave me this link, might be useful: [planets and sun maps](http://planetpixelemporium.com/planets.html). Be careful with the licenses, though, there ought to be free sources.